# Слои, z-index, перекрытие слоев

Tags: html, css, dropdown, z-index

Выпадающее меню кнопки попадает по слой другого элемента, который находится ниже. Хотя у выпадающего меню явно указано абсолютное позиционирование и высокий z-index.
Страница на boostrap, выпадающее меню с классом drop-down.
Самому элементу, под который попадает выпадающее меню, явно указываю z-index: -1, но ситуацию даже и это не спасает, элемент теряет видимость, но все также перекрывает выпадающее меню.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать что юы выпадающее меню, было поверх всех слоев ?

Comment: очевидно нужно показать свою разметку и css

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, архив со страницей, и подключаемыми файлами. http://dropmefiles.com/7GXwH

Comment: Всё связанное с вопросом должно быть там. Можно нажать ссылочку "править" под вопросом, открыть сниппет, добавить туда нужные элементы и вставить в вопрос

Comment: Скорее всего, код не нужен, попробуйте прочитать мой ответ ниже

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что вы скорее всего не понимаете, как он, `z-index`, работает. [Статья по теме](https://habrahabr.ru/post/166435/).

> Если вы попробуете установить z-index на не позиционированный элемент,
>   то ничего не произойдет. Во вторых, значения z-index могут создавать
>   контексты наложения. Хм, всё стало намного сложнее, не так ли?

...

> Каждый контекст наложения имеет свой корневой элемент в HTML
>   структуре. В момент формирования нового контекста на элементе, все
>   дочерние элементы так же попадают в этот контекст и занимают своё
>   место в порядке наложения. Если элемент располагается в самом низу
>   одного контекста наложения, то никаким мыслимым и немыслимым образом
>   не получится отобразить его над другим элементом в соседнем контексте
>   наложения, располагающимся выше по иерархии, даже с установленным
>   z-index равным миллиону.

У вас либо первый, либо второй, либо смешение обоих вариантов.

Answer (score 0):

Задайте z-index родительскому элементу вашего меню выше, чем родительскому элементу плашки под которую закатилось меню.

Ну и не забудьте указать позиционирование для родительских элементов. Например, relative.